# UIImage with bottom reflex

Tags: objective-c, ios, reflection, uiimageview, uiimage

is there any simple way to add a reflex to an UIImage or UIImageView just like the icons on the iPhone dock?

I couldn't find any native support for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for it is apple's sample code on [reflection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reflection/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Nice. I've implemented the 3 methods in this example but I'm getting this:
[FirstViewController reflectedImage:withHeight:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d2e20. 

Any idea why?

Comment: Thats how I'm using it: ivwAlbumReflex.image = [self reflectedImage:ivwAlbum withHeight:35];